# How to update DataFrame without making column type implicitly changed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following code

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['a', 'b'],
    'age': [1, 2]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['a'],
    'age': [3]
})
df1.update(df2)
```

df1 becomes

```
    name    age
0   a       3.0
1   b       2.0
```

But what I want is

```
    name    age
0   a       3
1   b       2
```

I can do `df1['age'] = df1['age'].astype(np.int64)`, but it feels a little awkward, especially if there are more columns.
Is there a better/more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is use original dtypes and pass to [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
d = df1.dtypes
df1.update(df2)
df1 = df1.astype(d)
print (df1)
  name  age
0    a    3
1    b    2
```

If need update rows by `name` solution failed, because use index for match, check edited data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['a', 'b'],
    'age': [1, 2]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['a','c','b'],
    'age': [3,4,8]
})

d = df1.dtypes
df1.update(df2)
df1 = df1.astype(d)
print (df1)
  name  age
0    a    3
1    c    4 <- replaced by index 1 both values
```

Correct solution is set index by `name`:

```
d = df1.dtypes

df11 = df1.set_index('name')
df22 = df2.set_index('name')

df11.update(df22)

df1 = df11.reset_index().astype(d)
print (df1)
  name  age
0    a    3
1    b    8 <- replaced by index 'b'
```